# Linear system equation with matrices

Tags: matrices

Given 2 square matrices $A$ and $B$, $A\neq B$, could we find a square matrix $X$, such that 
$$AX={\bf 0}\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;BX={\bf 0}?$$

and $X \neq {\bf 0}$.

Comment: if X is a Zero matrix, sure.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot but that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $X=0$ is a solution

Now, in order to find a non-trivial solution:

1. Find a linear base $\{u_1,\dot,u_k\}$ for $Ker(A)$
2. Find a linear base $\{v_1,\dot,v_m\}$ for $Ker(B)$
3. Concatenate them into a matrix $C$ of size $n \times (k+m)$
4. Find $Ker(C)$

The numbers of degrees of freedom is $Dim(Ker(C))$

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Let $X$ be the zero matrix. For example, a $2\times 2$ zero matrix would be \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Thanks, I forgot but that restriction.